# OpenGL PyOpenGL Framebuffer object not working: glGenFramebuffers missing

Tags: opengl, gpu, framebuffer, pyopengl

I have two systems with seemingly same `OpenGL` version and extensions support but `Framebuffer`s don't seem to be working on one of them.

A system with the `Intel HD 4000 Graphics Card`.(**FRAMEBUFFER WORKS HERE**)
Here is the output of **`glxinfo | grep OpenGL`**:

```
OpenGL vendor string: Intel Open Source Technology Center
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) Ivybridge Mobile 
OpenGL core profile version string: 3.3 (Core Profile) Mesa 10.1.0
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 3.30
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile
OpenGL core profile extensions:
OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 10.1.0
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.30
```

This is the output of **`glxinfo | grep framebuffer`**:

```
GLX_ARB_framebuffer_sRGB, GLX_ARB_multisample, 
GLX_EXT_create_context_es2_profile, GLX_EXT_framebuffer_sRGB, 
GLX_ARB_framebuffer_sRGB, GLX_ARB_get_proc_address, GLX_ARB_multisample, 
GLX_EXT_framebuffer_sRGB, GLX_EXT_import_context, 
GLX_ARB_framebuffer_sRGB, GLX_ARB_get_proc_address, GLX_ARB_multisample, 
GLX_EXT_create_context_es2_profile, GLX_EXT_framebuffer_sRGB, 
GL_ARB_fragment_shader, **GL_ARB_framebuffer_object**, 
GL_ARB_framebuffer_sRGB, GL_ARB_get_program_binary, 
GL_EXT_draw_instanced, GL_EXT_framebuffer_blit, 
GL_EXT_framebuffer_multisample, GL_EXT_framebuffer_multisample_blit_scaled, 
GL_EXT_framebuffer_sRGB, GL_EXT_packed_depth_stencil, GL_EXT_packed_float, 
GL_ARB_fragment_shader, GL_ARB_framebuffer_object, 
GL_ARB_framebuffer_sRGB, GL_ARB_get_program_binary, 
GL_EXT_framebuffer_blit, GL_EXT_framebuffer_multisample, 
GL_EXT_framebuffer_multisample_blit_scaled, GL_EXT_framebuffer_object, 
GL_EXT_framebuffer_sRGB, GL_EXT_gpu_program_parameters,
```

---

Here is another system where `Framebuffer` is **NOT** being generated.

Output of **`glxinfo | grep OpenGL`**:

```
OpenGL vendor string: Intel Open Source Technology Center
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) Ivybridge Mobile 
OpenGL core profile version string: 3.3 (Core Profile) Mesa 10.3.0-devel (git-ecee4c4 saucy-oibaf-ppa)
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 3.30
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile
OpenGL core profile extensions:
OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 10.3.0-devel (git-ecee4c4 saucy-oibaf-ppa)
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.30
```

Output of **`glxinfo | grep framebuffer`**:

```
GLX_ARB_framebuffer_sRGB, GLX_ARB_get_proc_address, GLX_ARB_multisample, 
GLX_EXT_fbconfig_packed_float, GLX_EXT_framebuffer_sRGB, 
**GL_ARB_framebuffer_object**, GL_ARB_framebuffer_sRGB, 
GL_EXT_draw_instanced, GL_EXT_framebuffer_blit, 
GL_EXT_framebuffer_multisample, GL_EXT_framebuffer_multisample_blit_scaled, 
GL_EXT_framebuffer_sRGB, GL_EXT_packed_depth_stencil, GL_EXT_packed_float, 
GL_ARB_fragment_shader, GL_ARB_framebuffer_object, 
GL_ARB_framebuffer_sRGB, GL_ARB_get_program_binary, 
GL_EXT_framebuffer_blit, GL_EXT_framebuffer_multisample, 
GL_EXT_framebuffer_multisample_blit_scaled, GL_EXT_framebuffer_object, 
GL_EXT_framebuffer_sRGB, GL_EXT_gpu_program_parameters,
```

The `GL_ARB_framebuffer_object` is the extension which enables `Framebuffer` support with `OpenGL`. Both systems have them but still one does not work.

I was using `Python` (`PyOpenGL`) and used the following function to check what all functions exist using `print dir(OpenGL.GL)` and saving the output to a file. I was surprised to find that despite the existence of the Framebuffer extension, the function
`glGenFramebuffers` was missing.

What could be the issue here?

Comment: See ***Issue (8)*** [here](https://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/framebuffer_object.txt) *"Unlike most ARB extensions, this is a strict subset of functionality already approved in OpenGL 3.0. This extension exists only to support that functionality on older hardware that cannot implement a full OpenGL 3.0 driver."* `GL_ARB_framebuffer_object` does not do what you think it does, a GL 3.0 implementation already guarantees this functionality and the FBO extension does not change anything. The only reason you would ever check for that extension is if you do not have a 3.0 implementation.

Comment: Now, as for your actual question... rather than printing the output of `glxinfo`, is there any chance you could check these things during your GL program's runtime? You could be picking a pixel format that throws you off the GL 3.0 path on one of those pieces of hardware.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman It was just in some other module which is quite strange.

Answer (score 0):

On `Python 2.7.5+`, the `Framebuffer` objects are available in a separate module.

The module is: **`OpenGL.GL.framebufferobjects`**

Whereas on `Python 2.7.6` and above, it is available directly inside: **`OpenGL.GL`**.